# Does the crypto wallet "Exodus" reveal your IP Address?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

I've read that "SPV Wallets," also called "thin wallets," such as Electrum, reveal some personal information such as your IP address. Apparently this is different than a "full node" wallet that downloads the entire blockchain.

When searching, I didn't find info on the classification of the "Exodus" wallet (desktop application) or the MEWConnect wallet (phone application) of "MyEtherWallet.com."

Does these wallets reveal your IP address? Why or why not?

I hope my terminology is accurate - I am novice with this stuff.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

IF you connect to someone else you ALWAYS reveal your IP to someone.
There a 2 types of "Thin wallets"

1. Centralized
2. SPV

When using a centralized wallet you always send transaction, and receive data through the same server which is provided by your wallet receiver. If the server shuts down your wallet is not usable (except if you export your private keys). The and only this server receives your IP

With SPV wallets you connect to multiple randomly selected wallets (mostly three). All of them get your IP. However it is more decentralized because it verirfes the authenticity from multiple peers.

Sharing IPs with multiple people is a fundamental and neccesary concept in P2P networks. If you really want to go secure use a VPN or Tor. Bitcoin Core has a feature to run over Tor.

Answer (score 0):

I also thought about VPN, cause whatever wallet is it electrum, ownr wallet or exodus they show your address when you are connected